# dhclient hooks don't run automatically

Tags: raspbian, dhcp

I am trying to make Raspbian execute a bash script every time its IP changes. I placed my script in **/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d** but it does not execute after a reboot.  It does execute if I manually run:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

The file permissions are the same as other files.  The default demo does not run either.

Comment: `dhcpcd` and `dhclient` are two different applications that can serve the same purpose.  The former is part of the default networking used by Rasbpian, the latter is not, which might explain why your script does not run when you think it should.

Comment: Do you installed `dhclient` and disabled `dhcpcd`?

Comment: dhcpcd is running.  I don't recall installing dhclient

Comment: Just for interesting: do you expect to get an event from a changed ip address that can trigger your script? Or do you do some polling? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 0):

> dhcpcd is running. I don't recall installing dhclient

You may or may not need to install `dhclient` -- I think it is probably the latter, and in any case it is installed -- but it does not *run automatically by default*. However, `dhcpcd` does, as you have acknowledged above.

Running both of these things at the same time will probably lead to problems in a context where the network configuration is simple: You have an end-user system with one connection to a (W)LAN which provides access to the internet.  This normally does require DHCP negotiation with a router, but **you only need one application to do this** and certainly will **NOT** benefit if you try to use several of them at the same time.

If you prefer to use `dhclient`, disable the `dhcpcd` process. If you then want to be online at boot **you will then have to configure or create some service to do this**.

Put simply: `dhclient` **does not run at boot by default**, which explains why hook scripts written for it will not run then either.